# Updating outer monad only in monad transformer

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I have a monad for a computation that may fail and does some logging:

```
f1 :: WriterT [String] (Either String) a
```

I have a function that will not fail but does some logging:

```
f2 :: Writer [String] b
```

What's the best way to update the writer monad in f1 using the log from f2, and capture the output of the f2 computation? At the moment I'm doing this:

```
f2result <- (\(r,l) -> do {tell l; return r}) (runWriter f2)
```

I am using lift to update the inner monad with a different computation, so switching around the Writer and Either monads will not solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks danr and rampion for your responses. I've chosen to use the wrap method. Although I could change the type of f2, that function appears in other contexts, therefore I'd like to write its type without reference to the needs of a particular calling function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you defined `f2`, the easiest possible approach may be to refactor `f2` so it's defined thusly:

```
 f2 :: Monad m => WriterT [String] m b
```

Which shouldn't be too hard, since `Writer w b` is defined as `WriterT w Identity b`, and the `Identity` monad doesn't give you anything.

Then you'd be able to chain them just by doing `f1 >> f2`.

If you can't redefine `f2`, you could always define your own with the appropriate signature:

```
 f2' :: Monad m => WriterT [String] m b
 f2' = WriterT . return $ runWriter f2
```

And if you've a bunch of `f2` to wrap, you could always define a function to wrap them for you

```
 wrap :: Monad m => Writer w b -> WriterT w m b
 wrap = WriterT . return . runWriter
```

So you can do `f1 >> wrap f2a >> wrap f2b >> wrap f2c ...`

Answer (score 4):

As a follow up on rampion's answer, you can instead refactor `f2`
on any `MonadWriter`:

```
f2 :: MonadWriter [String] m => m a
```

Should in not be possible to change its definition you can
wrap it similarly as rampion does:

```
f2' :: MonadWriter [String] m => m a
f2' = do let (a,w) = runWriter f2
         tell w
         return a
```

The `[String]` argument to `MonadWriter` requires this GHC pragma:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
```

As always, pragmas are put on the top of the module.

In the comments, rampion gave a version of wrapping a function in this setting:

```
wrap :: MonadWriter w m => Writer w b -> m b
wrap = uncurry (<<) . (return *** tell) . runWriter 
  where (<<) = flip (>>)
```

Comment: and the wrapper becomes `wrap :: MonadWriter w m => Writer w b -> m b; wrap = uncurry (<<) . (return *** tell) . runWriter where (<<) = flip (>>)`

Comment: Well, let me join the mutual admiration society, and say that I can appreciate the generalization to the MonadWriter typeclass :)